# Overlay layer with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create an overlay layer that will cover my screen entirely with semi-transparent layer when an element is clicked. I'm struggling with appending it to the document:

```
#overlay { 
   background-image: url(../overlay.png);
   opacity: 0.5;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 1000;
}

$("#getOverlay").click(function() {
    var overlay = $('<div id="overlay">');
    $('body').append(overlay);
});
```

The layer works fine if I just place in my document. Getting it there on click is the problem for some reason.

---

UPDATED:

I just realized that i was testing it under IE tab (FF plugin) which mimics an older version of IE. FF and IE9 act as intended. Older IE apparently does not recognize transparency, so I modified CSS:

```
#overlay { 
   background-image: url(../overlay.png);
   filter:alpha(opacity=50);
   -moz-opacity:0.5;
   -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
   opacity: 0.5;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 12000;
}
```

Thanks all for your feedback!

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/hJqGP/) (with image replaced by color because I don't have access to your image).  Are you sure your click handler is getting bound?

Comment: Did you check it in multiple browsers with extensions and plug-ins disabled?

Comment: Is the button that triggers the overlay dynamically injected into the DOM or is it present on page load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me in this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/z8FmA/

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$("#getOverlay").click(function() {
    var overlay = $('<div>');
    overlay.addClass('overlay');
    $('body').append(overlay);
});
```

and if `$("#getOverlay")` is **not** there on DOM load try:

```
$("#getOverlay").live('click',function(){...
```

and change the 1st line of css to:

```
.overlay {
```

[see working DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/C9s7L/3/show/)

Answer (score 0):

You should add the overlay directly to the html like `<div id="overlay"></div>`, add a `display: none` to the css definition and then on the on click handler, do `$('#overlay').show()`. Otherwise you'll be add a new div to the body every time you click the element.

Comment: That's OK, I can remove it later, can't I? i think I'll be able to use remove()

Comment: I guess, it is an unnecessary use of resources, albeit very small